# Calendar view to disable people from clicking the links to the respectively items

Tags: calendar

May I know if there are any config to prevent people from clicking on the links on the calendar view of a SharePoint 2007? (e.g. In the picture below, there are 3 links such as "Meeting with Contoso manager". I don't want anyone to click on these links.)

Note: They can still click on other "menu" links such as "Day", "Week" and "Month".

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the Calendar Plugin from this website: http://www.queness.com/post/656/10-beautiful-jquery-and-mootool-calendar-plugins.

Inside the website, there are a few JQuery Calendar Plugin (such as FullCalendar and JCalendar) that you can use in conjunction with your List.

Comment: -1 Almost completely irrelevant, I'm afraid.

Comment: Hi Stuart, the asker is looking for ways to prevent users to click the events on the calendar. There are basically 2 ways, one offer by Amit (which the asker is finding difficulties to get it working as discussed in the comments above). The another method is using SPServices, retrieve all the events and store into a array. Then use one of the JQuery Calendar Plugin to show those events. I do not know if the asker know how to use a JQuery plugin but at the least, I offer the asker another alternative method and hopeful, it helps.

Comment: Thanks Anderson. Tried the JQuery Calendar Plugin - Full Calendar and now is working to what I asked for. Also Thanks everyone for providing solutions and help for my question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no setting to prevent the hyperlink click for calendar in Moss.

But you can do it with JQuery. You can disable individual links or all links in the calendar div.

Check out this link to find how to disable a link :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970388/jquery-disable-a-link

Comment: after reading the link you provided, may I know how (or where) do I insert the following code into the SharePoint 2007 page?  (Do I need to use a webpart to insert the code or ...?) `$('#MontlyViewDefault_CalendarView').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});`

Comment: You can insert the code to the master page or the individual page (using SharePoint Designer). You can also add content editor webpart on the page and insert it in the webpart. Ensure that you also have jquery library reference before the script.

Comment: Strange, I am still able to click each of the items in the calendar even though I have [1] import jquery library reference and [2] insert my code into the javascript tag. Any insight?

Comment: You should construct correct jquery for that. Use this one:

$(document).ready(function(){         
                  
 $('#MontlyViewDefault_CalendarView a').attr("href","#");
 $('#MontlyViewDefault_CalendarView a').attr("onclick","");  
       
});

Comment: Strange, I am still able to click on each of the link even I used your jquery. I put it insider `<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">` tag, is it correct or I have to put in other tag?

Comment: The script I provided is a tested one and will work if you place it in the above placeholder, provided you know the basics of how to use javascript or jquery in a page...If not please check out : http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works

Comment: Yes, I need import the Jquery. I insert this code `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js">` right above your code and places both code in the PlaceholderAdditionalPageHead tag. That is why I was wondering if I still miss out something else...

Comment: Download the jquery to a document library and use like :                   <asp:content contentplaceholderid="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
<script  src="/Style Library/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >

$(document).ready(function(){ 

 $('#MontlyViewDefault_CalendarView a').attr("href","#");
 $('#MontlyViewDefault_CalendarView a').attr("onclick","");  
       
});

</script>
 
</asp:content>

Comment: Strange, I am still able to clock on each of the link using your new code. Some more, it give me a script error `SCRIPT5007: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object` pointing at the dollar sign in `$(document).ready(function()`. Previously, there was no such error. Very Strange.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1695/discussion-between-amit-kumawat-and-larry-morries)

Answer (score 0):

I already found solution. In case if some one else want use here is the JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/js/jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(
    MyCalendarHook, 
    "SP.UI.ApplicationPages.Calendar.js");
    function MyCalendarHook() {     
    var _patchCalendar = function() {        
        $('.ms-acal-rootdiv .ms-acal-item').click(function (e) {
            //var itemId = $('a', $(this)).attr('href').split('?ID=')[1];
            //alert('Item with ID ' + itemId + ' was clicked!');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    };

    var _onItemsSucceed = SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarStateHandler.prototype.onItemsSucceed;
    SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarStateHandler.prototype.onItemsSucceed = function($p0, $p1) {
        _onItemsSucceed.call(this, $p0, $p1);
        _patchCalendar();
    };
}
  </script>
```

Just paste this code in PlaceHolderBodyAreaClass tag.

You can also refer this link http://mhusseini.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/handle-clicks-on-calendar-items-in-sharepoint-2010-with-javascript/