# Unable to read doc extension file from SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, csom, file

I am using the code below to read files from SharePoint 2019 server. It works perfectly for docx file extension but with doc files it throw an error. Can you guy s help me out here please?

```
 using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://sharepoint2019/sites/test/"))
        {
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientResult<System.IO.Stream> stream = null;

            KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(clientContext);

            keywordQuery.QueryText = "SharePoint";

            keywordQuery.EnablePhonetic = true;

            keywordQuery.EnableOrderingHitHighlightedProperty = true;
            //keywordQuery.SummaryLength = 500;


            SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(clientContext);

            ClientResult<ResultTableCollection> results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


            //sometime if the same query has been made several time,an automatic favorite query is generated so we need to check else the correct rows wont be returned
            if (results.Value.Count > 1)
            {
                NumberOfRow = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                NumberOfRow = 0;
            }

            foreach (var resultRow in results.Value[NumberOfRow].ResultRows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} ({2}) {3}", resultRow["Title"], resultRow["Path"], resultRow["Write"], resultRow["HitHighlightedSummary"]);

                File file = clientContext.Web.GetFileByUrl(resultRow["Path"].ToString());
                stream = file.OpenBinaryStream();
                clientContext.Load(file);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


                if (resultRow["FileExtension"].ToString() == "pdf")
                {

                    Filebody = GetTextFromPDF(resultRow["Path"].ToString());
                }

                else if (resultRow["FileExtension"].ToString() == "docx" || resultRow["FileExtension"].ToString() == "doc")
                {


                        WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream.Value, false);

                        body = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;


                        Filebody = body.InnerText;
```

Error message:

> 'File contains corrupted data.' at line WordprocessingDocument
>   wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream.Value,
>   false);

Comment: What part is failing?

Comment: It seems like You have lost some part of ending code - please provide full code. And agree with @JamesRandal - could You specify which part is failing and what error are You receiving?

Comment: @JamesRandal question updated

Comment: @KristapsVilerts Question updated

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message (and on command [WordprocessingDocument](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.packaging.wordprocessingdocument?view=openxml-2.8.1)) I assume You are trying to get content of Word documents.

Problem is following - DOCX type of documents are OpenXML based so they can be opened as an archive file (for example, with 7zip) and will contain a lot of XML files and relations. [This article by Stepan Yakovenko](https://www.toptal.com/xml/an-informal-introduction-to-docx)  has good cover on working with DOCX type files.

Contrary, DOC type documents are stored in binary, so content cannot be read by OpenXml libraries.

So the answer to question/problem - **this code is meant to be used with DOCX type documents, but not for DOC type.**

Update after comment request - look for "**Microsoft Word interop**" library. See this super simple [example by Dotnetperls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/word)  of how to get content of DOC type file.

Comment: can you kindly  provide code that will open SharePoint doc file.

Comment: Updated my answer (and please consider my edit to Your question about error message formatting - it is not a simple text and not a regular sentence).

Comment: am getting the following error now : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154

Comment: To use Microsoft Word interop , there is a need that office is installed on the server the code is running which is not the case for me

Comment: That is true - unfortunately, I do not see any other way (besides Microsoft Word interop) how to read DOC file content.

Comment: Now the issue is i can't install office on the same server SharePoint is running. Correct me if am wrong

Comment: That is another problem (another question) - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22348